# Checkstyle installation error Intellij Idea

Tags: java, plugins, intellij-idea, checkstyle, sevntu-checkstyle

I am trying to install Checkstyle including the SevNTU Checkstyle extension in IntelliJ IDEA as by

https://github.com/sevntu-checkstyle/sevntu.checkstyle/wiki/How-to-use-SevNTU-Checkstyle-in-Intellij-IDEA

However, i got an error when i am adding configuration file sevntu-checkstyle-default-configuration.xml:

```
org.infernus.idea.checkstyle.exception.CheckStylePluginException: <html><b>The Checkstyle rules file could not be loaded.</b><br>
    cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Unable to instantiate com.github.sevntu.checkstyle.checks.design.VariableDeclarationUsageDistanceCheck<br>
    The file has been blacklisted for 60s.</html>
at org.infernus.idea.checkstyle.checker.CheckerFactory.blacklistAndShowMessage(CheckerFactory.java:183)
at org.infernus.idea.checkstyle.checker.CheckerFactory.createChecker(CheckerFactory.java:139)
at org.infernus.idea.checkstyle.checker.CheckerFactory.getOrCreateCachedChecker(CheckerFactory.java:84)
at org.infernus.idea.checkstyle.checker.CheckerFactory.checker(CheckerFactory.java:63)
at org.infernus.idea.checkstyle.checker.CheckerFactory.verify(CheckerFactory.java:44)
at org.infernus.idea.checkstyle.ui.LocationDialogue.attemptLoadOfFile(LocationDialogue.java:198)
at org.infernus.idea.checkstyle.ui.LocationDialogue.access$800(LocationDialogue.java:24)
at org.infernus.idea.checkstyle.ui.LocationDialogue$NextAction.actionPerformed(LocationDialogue.java:241)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:751)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:724)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:721)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.e(IdeEventQueue.java:734)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:565)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:382)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:184)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:229)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1654)
at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1606)
at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
at org.infernus.idea.checkstyle.ui.LocationDialogue.setVisible(LocationDialogue.java:151)
at org.infernus.idea.checkstyle.ui.CheckStyleConfigPanel$AddLocationAction.actionPerformed(CheckStyleConfigPanel.java:324)
at org.infernus.idea.checkstyle.ui.CheckStyleConfigPanel$ToolbarAction.run(CheckStyleConfigPanel.java:399)
at org.infernus.idea.checkstyle.ui.CheckStyleConfigPanel$ToolbarAction.run(CheckStyleConfigPanel.java:394)
at com.intellij.ui.ToolbarDecorator$3.doAdd(ToolbarDecorator.java:433)
at com.intellij.ui.CommonActionsPanel$Buttons.performAction(CommonActionsPanel.java:70)
at com.intellij.ui.CommonActionsPanel$MyActionButton.actionPerformed(CommonActionsPanel.java:247)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:182)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.a(ActionButton.java:162)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.a(ActionButton.java:126)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.processMouseEvent(ActionButton.java:303)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:751)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:724)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:721)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.e(IdeEventQueue.java:734)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:565)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:382)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:184)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:229)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:778)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:465)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.invokeShow(DialogWrapper.java:1614)
at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1571)
at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowSettingsUtilImpl.showSettingsDialog(ShowSettingsUtilImpl.java:114)
at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowSettingsAction.actionPerformed(ShowSettingsAction.java:65)
at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher$3.performAction(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:593)
at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.processAction(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:644)
at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.d(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:483)
at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:213)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:538)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:382)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Thank you for help

Comment: Also i tried to follow some advices, but got the same problem each time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for your problem is that the [sevntu-checkstyle-default-configuration.xml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sevntu-checkstyle/sevntu.checkstyle/gh-pages/sevntu-checkstyle-default-configuration.xml) linked in the current version of the GitHub [wiki document](https://github.com/sevntu-checkstyle/sevntu.checkstyle/wiki/How-to-use-SevNTU-Checkstyle-in-Intellij-IDEA) is outdated. The *VariableDeclarationUsageDistance* check was moved to the regular Checkstyle tool with SevNTU Checkstyle 1.13.0, so it does not exist in SevNTU Checkstyle anymore.

This can really only be fixed by the SevNTU guys, so you may consider [opening an issue](https://github.com/sevntu-checkstyle/sevntu.checkstyle/issues) with them. Until it gets fixed, I believe your best bet is to remove checks that cause errors from the file until it works.

You did not give version numbers, but you are probably using the current versions, which means Checkstyle 6.10.1 and SevNTU Checkstyle 1.13.6. Those are [not fully compatible](http://checkstyle-addons.thomasjensen.com/checkstyle-compatibility-matrix.html). Consider using [Checkstyle-IDEA 4.17.3](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1065?pr=&showAllUpdates=true) for best compatibility with the SevNTU Checkstyle extension.

Comment: You were right, i used Checkstyle 6.10.1 and SevNTU Checkstyle 1.13.6.
Now i installed Checkstyle-IDEA 4.17.3 and SevNTU Checkstyle < 1.13.0 and there were no errors. Thank you for help!